# Is the any way for Next-Auth with google provider to invoke pop-up window instead of redirect to another page?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, google-signin, next-auth

I am trying to implement google authentication but the requirements of the projects says Pop-Up window login instead of redirect. Is there any solution like uxMode="popup"?

I think there is not an available option, but I was wondering if there is a work around.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/arye321/nextauth-google-popup-login

Comment: Thank you Linus! I was hoping for something more clean but this solution is ok. I will proceed with that.